# How to extract a column from Mongodb in R?

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I have a mongoDb with the name 'consumerco' and i need to extract a column from it with the name 'Company' into my R studio as a table. How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mongolite` package try:
`mongoConnection <- mongo(db = "consumerco", collection = "mycolection", url = "mongodb://000.000.00", verbose = TRUE)`

Assuming you field is `species` this query calls all records with some conditions:

```
mySmallDf <- mongoConnection$find(
                      query = '{"field1":"ValueX"}',
                      fields = '{"species" : 1, "field2":1, "_id":0}')
```

And returns all values with 1 in the `fields`argument. _id becomes by default so if you don want it set `"_id":0`

Comment: But what if i want to extract an entire column ? I want one whole column from the database with all it's rows. With no conditions

Comment: Omit the `query` argument: `mySmallDf <- mongoConnection$find(fields = '{"species" : 1, "field2":1, "_id":0}')`